# Asus ROG GL553VW Keyboard Backlight, Fan Control and Keyboard Shortcuts working thanks to Zlynt but now the touchpad isn't recognized

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, asus

Zlynt's fix corrects the Keyboard Backlight, Fan Control and Keyboard Shortcuts but now the touchpad isn't recognized.  Before this fix the touchpad worked as it should.  Please help.

Edit: Issue solved by rebuilding the lastest stable Linux Kernel and changing the file drivers/hid/hid-ids.h in the Linux kernel with the following changes (accoding to apeelme at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194557):

-#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x1837

+#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x8176